# Yeoman generator produces an old version of SPFx

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework

I have Yeoman generator (@microsoft/generator-sharepoint) version 1.8.2, I can verify this by running: `npm list --depth=0 -g` .. When I try to run yo @microsoft/sharepoint , I noticed 2 things:

The wizard doesn't show support for SharePoint 2019, so it only gives me the choice of SharePoint online only, or SharePoint 2016 onwards. The second thing is that the project scaffolded shows this:

```
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.5.1"
```

What do I need to do to get the latest version of SPFx? (1.8).

Comment: If you're developing for SharePoint Server 2019, the highest SPFx version it supports is 1.4.1.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorSeward. But I am not even getting the chance to choose sp 2019 in the first place. The yeoman wizard gives me the option to either choose SP online or sp 2016, if I go with SP online, I'd get SPFx v 1.5 only.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue now. Any other ideas on how to fix. I've uninstalled/reinstalled node and updated to SPFX v1.10 but still getting 1.5.1 only.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before and it was because one of the following:

- there was a `.yo-repository` in a higher directory
- need to run `npm install -g yo@latest @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest`
- `node_modules` folder in a higher directory

Comment if any work for you!